# При адаптивности объекты прилипают к краям

Tags: html, css

При уменьшении разрешения объекты прилипают к краям экрана. Чтобы этого избежать:

1. для каждой секции при уменьшении задать `padding`?
2. как-то иначе можно?

Comment: Добавьте ваш [mcve] вопрос слишком общий

Comment: Уважаемый, здесь гадалок нет...

Comment: Зачем тут код? Что непонятного? Где вопрос слишком общий, если он уже некуда? Паддинги наиболее подходящий способ.

Comment: Много чего непонятного: К каким краям, какие объекты, какой паддинг. Это как математику в середине начать учить без примеров.

Comment: можно при медиа запросах уменьшить элементы путём `transform:scale(px или %);` или же `zoom: от 0.1 до 1;` но лучше конечно менять размеры ,margin и padding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выберите главную обертку, обычно это тег `main` или `<div class="wrapper"></div>` ну или `body` и ему задайте:

```
@media (max-width: 540px) {
  padding: 0 15px;
}
```